# Open a wav file on client using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, client-server, wav

I want to open wav file directly in my clients default player in asp.net c# .
I have used response methods,but it gives me a pop up to whether open or save. i dont want that i want the sound files be directly played as he clicks the link.

i HAVE ALSO used 
system.diagoniscs("") it only works in server

Need something to try Please.

Thanks

Comment: What you're requesting cannot be done in the form you suggest.  C# doesn't run on the client: as you have realised, C# code only runs on the server.  Alternative clientside technology such as Flash might help you here, but your requirements aren't clear enough to suggest a solution.

Comment: If you are using html5 only then take a look at the audio js object. But for backwards compatibility flash may be the way to go.